# Combined range-based for-loop

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop

Is it possible to combine two for loops if both loops contain same set of instructions. In my code I repeat this procedure frequently: Doing the same things for both containers. In each case, I don't want to make a function and call in both loops.

```
#include <array>
using std::array;

int main()
{
    array<int, 10> a;
    array<int, 10> b;

    for (int i: a)
    {
        // set of instructions
    }

    for (int i: b)
    {
        // set of instructions
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Update after three years:** Even I don't understand what I wanted. Why not use function or lambda function or traditional for-loop. Sorry I can't make the question clear but also don't want to delete it because there are answers below.

Comment: You'd have to combine the arrays into one structure.

Comment: What do you mean by *combine*? Do you want to iterate over both arrays together, or iterate over them separately but not repeat the code within the loop?

Comment: Why don't you want to make a _function_ call?

Comment: If you do not want to make a call in loops, use the inline function. This way you can write a function and still not make a call.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a *lambda expression* to execute the same instructions for both loops:

```
auto&& body = [&](int i) {
    /* set of instructions */
};
for (int i : a) { body(i); }
for (int i : b) { body(i); }
```

In contrast to an explicit function, the lambda expression can access all local variables.

Comment: OP has a weird requirement that a function call not be made within the loop, and invoking the lambda is no different from a function call.

Comment: @juanchopanza: There is a difference between what somebody _wants_ and what somebody _needs_. The OP didn't explain, why he doesn't want function calls. Currently, one can only speculate. However, a lambda expression as shown above has basically no drawback compared to executing the instructions inline.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible, because the arrays are independent.

The range based for loop expands to this :

```
for ( auto it = a.begin(); a.end != it; ++ it )
{
  // instructions
}
```

As you can see, it creates an iterator. And it is not possible to get such iterator that iterates over two independent arrays.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming what you're asking for is how to iterate over both arrays together, in a single `for` loop. This can be done using [`boost::zip_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/libs/iterator/doc/zip_iterator.html), combined with [`boost::iterator_range`](http://www.boost.org/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/utilities/iterator_range.html) which allows us to use a range-based `for`

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/range/iterator_range.hpp>
#include <boost/iterator/zip_iterator.hpp>

int main() 
{
  std::array<int, 4> a{{1, 2, 3, 4}};
  std::array<int, 4> b{{10, 20, 30, 40}};

  for(auto const& tup : 
        boost::make_iterator_range(
          boost::make_zip_iterator(boost::make_tuple(a.begin(), b.begin())),
          boost::make_zip_iterator(boost::make_tuple(a.end(), b.end())))) {
    std::cout << tup.get<0>() << ' ' << tup.get<1>() << '\n';
  }
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/abed5077208ffceb)

---

On the other hand, if all you want to do is iterate over the arrays separately, but avoid code duplication within the loop bodies, then create a function that takes a (maybe `const`) reference to the `std::array` and then iterates over it.

Answer (score 1):

I am really curious how you would achieve that with a default loop that you are asking it specifically a range based loop. Have you thought of merging the arrays, which would be costly but that would be your second best bet; since, as everyone mentioned, a function call is the most optimal for your scenario. Something like:

```
void loop_function(const std::array<int> &array) {
     for(int i : array) {
         // blah blah...    
     }   
}
```